# How can we know reason \$9.6[dB]\$ from this graph?

Tags: rf

[image]

The diagram can be found at [graph link](https://blog.minicircuits.com/every-block-covered-cascaded-p1db-and-ip3-in-a-26-ghz-5g-front-end/)

A lot of textbook give this formula.

$$IP3 = P_{1dB} [dBm] + 9.6[dB]$$

*This equation is valid for both input and output referred quantities.*

But how can we know reason \$9.6[dB]\$ from this graph?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But how can we know reason 9.6[dB] from this graph?

That comes from heavy math and approximations using [Taylor expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series).

I will not do the entire math here but here's a summary:

The presence of harmonics allows us to approximate a system's output (for a sinusoidal input e.g. \$v_i=v \cos(\omega t)\$) using Taylor expansion and half-angle formulas (trigonometry):

$$
\begin{align}
v_o&=a \ v_i \\
&=a (v \cos (\omega t))\\
&=a_0+a_1 (v \cos (\omega t))+a_2(v \cos (\omega t))^2+a_3 (v \cos (\omega t))^3+... \\
&=(a_0+\frac{1}{2}a_2v_2+\frac{3}{8}a_4v_4+...)+(a_1+\frac{3}{4}a_3v_2+...) \ v\cos(\omega t) +...
\end{align}
$$

\$P_{1\mathrm{dB}}\$ (1 dB compression point) can be calculated from ideal vs real fundamental components of the approximation above i.e. ideal fundamental: \$a_1v \cos(\omega t)\$ and real (approx) fundamental: \$(a_1+\frac{3}{4}a_3v_2+...) \ v\cos(\omega t)\$

Using the expansion you can also find IP3 (\$P_{\mathrm{IP3}}\$) i.e. the point (input power) where the output third harmonic and the output fundamental powers are equal. But this first requires the Taylor expansion above to be re-written from a multi-frequency input e.g. \$v_i=v_1\cos (\omega_1 t)+v_2\cos (\omega_2 t)\$.

---

Now the main assumption is that the system's output has components up to the 4th order. This allows you to write the IP3 point in terms of \$P_{1\mathrm{dB}}\$. Therefore

$$
R=\frac{P_{\mathrm{IP3}}}{P_{1\mathrm{dB}}}=\frac{1}{1-10^{-1/20}}\approx 9.2 \ \mathrm{W/W}
$$

Or in dB:

$$
R_{dB}=10\log (R)\approx 9.6 \ \mathrm{dB}
$$

Comment: Any link for \$v_0 = a v_i\$? I want to know how they expand this equation.

Comment: @kile I didn't deliberately indicate that but if a system is linear then the input-output relation will be like \$v_o= a \ v_i\$. For the rest, use \$v_i=v \ \cos(\omega t)\$ for assumption of sinusoid input. Real systems are not linear, and for the sake of simplicity the system is taken as "close to linear". For harmonics approximation Taylor expansion is used.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a theoretical background only.

Here is what I got with a simple mixer from [microcap v12](https://archive.org/details/mc12cd_202110).

See the "distorted" line for IM3.

[image]